# Defining classes in ontology, instanciating individuals in namespace

Tags: python, owl, ontology, owlready

Using Owlready2, how to define classes attached to the ontology (on this base iri: http://example.com/ontology/item/1.1#) and when an individual is created, it would be defined on other iri (like: http://example.com/profile/item/resource/) ?

So if i instanciate a defined class **Stuff** inheriting **owlready2.Thing**:

```
    from owlready2 import *
    from rdflib import URIRef

    onto = get_ontology('http://example.com/ontology/item/1.1#')
    
    class Stuff(Thing):
        namespace = onto
    
    stuff = Stuff(
        name='8gdfb186-fc78-4b9e-95c4-545339d3ce1b',
        namespace='http://example.com/profile/item/resource/'
    )
```

and then i save the ontology to a new file, it would have something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
         xml:base="http://www.perfect-memory.com/ontology/item/1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.perfect-memory.com/ontology/item/1.1#">

<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.com/ontology/item/1.1"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/ontology/item/1.1#Stuff">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
</owl:Class>

<Stuff rdf:about="http://example.com/profile/item/resource/8gdfb186-fc78-4b9e-95c4-545339d3ce1b">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
</Stuff>

</rdf:RDF>
```

BUT, this is quite unfriendly to use, as I generate the iri for my individual outside of anything related to ontology and owlready2. So i would like to do something like that:

```
stuff = Stuff('http://example.com/profile/item/resource/8gdfb186-fc78-4b9e-95c4-545339d3ce1b')
```

How could I achieve that?

I tried to overload the `__new__` method when instanciating, without success:

```
from owlready2 import *
from rdflib import URIRef

class Stuff(Thing):
    namespace = onto
    
    def __new__(Class, name=None, namespace=None, is_a=None, **kwargs):
        if name and isinstance(name, URIRef):
            splitted = str(name).rsplit('/', 1)
            if len(splitted) == 2:
                new_namespace = onto.get_namespace(f'{splitted[0]}/')
                obj = Thing.__new__(
                    Class,
                    name=splitted[1],
                    namespace=new_namespace,
                    is_a=is_a,
                    **kwargs
                )
                obj.namespace = new_namespace
                obj.namespace.ontology._base_iri = f'{splitted[0]}/'
                obj.set_name(f'{splitted[1]}')
                return obj
        
        obj = Thing.__new__(
            Class,
            name=name,
            namespace=namespace,
            is_a=is_a,
            **kwargs
        )

        return obj
```

The new individual iri become: http://example.com/profile/item/resource/http://example.com/profile/item/resource/8gdfb186-fc78-4b9e-95c4-545339d3ce1b - of course that's not what i'm looking for.

Any ideas?

PS : As the owlready2 library is actually looking into all parents classes to generate ancestors for the current owlready2 mapped class, it's not possible to do some inheritance on mixins.

Answer (score 0):

With further development and research, I was able to achieve it using an **init** method overriding the Thing's one like that:

```
def __init__(self, name=None, namespace=None, is_a=None, **kwargs):
        if name and isinstance(name, URIRef):
            splitted = name.rsplit('/', 1)
            if len(splitted) == 2:
                new_namespace = onto.get_namespace(f'{splitted[0]}/')
                super().__init__(splitted[1], new_namespace, is_a, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(name, namespace, is_a, **kwargs)
```